# HTML 5 best practice - When and where should I use section or article?

Tags: html

There's a couple information about HTML 5, but I'm really confused about the best practices to use on my website especifically when and where I should use `section` or `article`. So what do you guys think of the following layout divisions?

[image]

*ps: The blue boxes are just some call to action like "buy now" or something like that.*

Comment: Personally I don't use articles for anything except content indices or full inner page articles, also making use of schema data. Your use of section appears correct to me. Where you have articles I would just use div. Without knowing the actual content I don't know if those blue boxes are indeed excerpts of inner pages or what

Comment: The blue boxes are just some call to action, like "buy now" or something like that. Tku

Comment: In that case I would ditch the article tags in favor of a more generic div

Comment: Please read [ask] and [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what's not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). From "what's not": questions where *every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”*

Answer (score 1):

This question is currently being flagged for being primarily opinion based, perhaps for good reason.

The best answer that could possibly be given to this question is to look at the [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element), which states:

> The `article` element [represents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#represents) a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.
>
> When `article` elements are nested, the inner `article` elements represent articles that are in principle related to the contents of the outer article. For instance, a blog entry on a site that accepts user-submitted comments could represent the comments as `article` elements nested within the `article` element for the blog entry.

So putting this into context with your question, I think you should be using `section` tags rather than `article`. Again, these are both block-level elements which should be functionally the same, making this answer subjective.